# How to do blue-green deployment for AWS Step Functions

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-deployment, aws-step-functions, blue-green-deployment

I am using AWS step function and I made some changes in state machine and activity worker. Activity code changes are not backward compatible. Also, activity code is deployed in my hosts (not hosted in AWS Lambda).

I saw some examples online to follow Blue-Green deplopyment: https://theburningmonk.com/2019/08/how-to-do-blue-green-deployment-for-step-functions/

But I am not using AWS Lambda, so what are the ways I can deploy my changes which are not backward compatible. How to do blue green deployment in aws step function when activites are hosted in non-AWS hosts.

Answer (score 0):

`so what are the ways I can deploy my changes which are not backward compatible`
Regardless of the tech, this is what exactly b/g deployment trying to prevent from happening.
In a breaking glass case, I don't think you even need a blue/green deployment.